# Android programming - screen resolution

Tags: android, resolution

I'm new to Android programming.
I've seen different phones with different screen resolutions that run on Android.
How can I create an application that works on all android devices with out any distortion in my application views.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is to size all your layout items in `dip`.  `dip` is short for `Density-independent pixel` and Android automatically scales items sized in `dip` to be the same size on different screens.  (You can shorten `dip` to `dp` in your layout XML files.)

The long answer is to [read this article on the Android developer website](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/practices/screens_support.html).  It is long but I highly recommended reading it from beginning to end at least once before you get too far with you application.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achieve Screen Independence..

- Use 9 patch images wherever possible
- Design Layout using dimension units as dp, sp and measurements(in, mm...etc).
- Use `fill_parent` and `wrap_content` wherever possible.
- Use resource along with qualifiers (Specifying resources for a group/type of device)
- Designing, scaling and fitting using custom coding for your program (Not recommended)
  Do read the following:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
(Take good look at testing, best practices more keenly)

Answer (score 1):

There are some best practices to have resolution independent app,

1. To use all 9 patch images.
2. To create layout according to Density Independent Pixel.