# Compensating for differences in Android devices? (video game programming)

Tags: android

Different Android devices have different screen sizes and screen densities.  When programming a video game, what is a good way to compensate for the differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend checking out all the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061258/multiple-screen-resolutions-aspect-ratios-games). This question is up for bounty, so a lot of people should be providing helpful answers.

Answer (score 2):

Well start with Android's documentation on [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).  You can also search for related qustions (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2703244/850332), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5815380/850332), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3804548/850332)) on StackOverflow.  This question has been asked often.  The advice for other Apps is just as applicable to games.